# Install httpd-devel on CentOS 5.7 x86_64

Tags: apache-2.2, yum

I'm trying to install httpd-devel on my Media Temple DV 4 server. I tried this:

```
yum install -y httpd-devel
```

But the install fails with:

```
--> Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 is needed by package httpd-devel-2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3.i386 (updates)
```

So that seems to indicate that I need a newer version of httpd. So I checked my httpd version. I checked my current version:

```
# yum info httpd
...
Installed Packages
Name       : httpd
Arch       : x86_64
Epoch      : 1
Version    : 2.2.19
Release    : 11072010
...
```

Ok so httpd-devel was asking for 2.2.3-53 but I only have 2.2.19. So I try to update httpd:

```
# yum update httpd
....
No Packages marked for Update
```

So with my limited knowledge I'm stuck, I can't install httpd-devel because it requires a newer version of httpd. But I can't update httpd because no packages are marked for update.

Thanks so much if anyone is able to point me in the right direction on this one.

Answer (score 1):

2.2.19 > 2.2.3

I think you must have installed httpd from a different repository.

What does:

> yum repolist

return?

Edit: rpm -qi httpd output:

```
[root@centos57 ~]# rpm -qi httpd
Name        : httpd                        Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2.2.3                             Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 53.el5.centos.3               Build Date: Thu 20 Oct 2011 09:05:30 PM UTC
Install Date: Mon 21 Nov 2011 04:53:32 PM UTC      Build Host: builder10.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Daemons    Source RPM: httpd-2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3.src.rpm
Size        : 3488328                          License: Apache Software License
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Thu 20 Oct 2011 09:13:11 PM UTC, Key ID a8a447dce8562897
URL         : http://httpd.apache.org/
Summary     : Apache HTTP Server
Description :
The Apache HTTP Server is a powerful, efficient, and extensible
web server.
```

Comment: Thanks, here is the result:  
    
  # yum repolist  
...  
repo id                        repo name                                  status  
base                           CentOS-5 - Base                            3,566  
extras                         CentOS-5 - Extras                            290  
updates                        CentOS-5 - Updates                           720  
repolist: 4,576

Comment: Sorry, just trying to figure out how line breaks work...

Comment: @Bruce, Hmm that's what I'd expect if just using CentOS repos. Check rpm -qi httpd, should look like the output I provided in edit

Comment: Looks similar, but the version and release are different:

Comment: # rpm -qi httpd

Name        : httpd                        Relocations: (not relocatable)

Version     : 2.2.19                            Vendor: Parallels

Release     : 11072010                      Build Date: Tue 19 Jul 2011 08:25:51 PM PDT
Install Date: Fri 23 Dec 2011 01:53:58 PM PST      Build Host: bcos5x64.plesk.ru
Group       : System Environment/Daemons    Source RPM: httpd-2.2.19-11072010.src.rpm
Size        : 3560809                          License: Apache Software License
Signature   : (none)
Packager    : Parallels <info@parallels.com>
Summary     : The Apache HTTP Server

Comment: Sorry first time on this forum. Still no idea how to do line breaks. No wonder I can't figure out these package versions ( ;

Comment: @Bruce, So it looks like it was provided by the Parallels Plesk Panel. So you'll need to get the httpd-devel package from it as well. Should probably ask your hosting provider about this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to it being a host/plesk-specific issue. It turns out Media Temple has a button in the control panel called "Install developer tools" this is the preferred way to install modules like this one. Hope this helps someone who has this issue in future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try running "yum clean all" and trying again.

That will clear the caches yum uses.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the httpd-x86_64 package is conflicting with the 32 bit version.

A simple `yum remove httpd.i386 -y && yum install httpd.x86_64 httpd-devel.x86_64 -y` should do the trick.